# Random walk governed by Markov Chain

Tags: markov-chain, random-walk

I'm trying to create an underlying markov chain whereby each state governs the probability distribution of a random walk for a stock index. Is there a more formal name for this type of process?

Comment: Could you define more mathematically this Markov chain ? ("a state governing the law of a random walk" and "a stock index" are quite unclear)

Comment: The Markov Chain is unclear to me as yet and I'd like to play around with the possibilities. It could be as simple as Boom or Bust with equal probabilities of staying the same or moving .to the next state, and in Boom the random walk increments follow a normal distribution and in Bust a t-distribution. Or there could be many more unclear states.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent He/she appears to be asking for the name of the code provided in my answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91575/random-walk-under-changing-conditions/91584#91584 I am also interested.